# toad hangs while fetching a column of datatype timestamp

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

When i open up toad sql editor and run a select statement on a column that has datatype of timestamp, then toad hangs every time. But when i do a `trunc` on the timestamp column, the data is returned quickly.
What is it about timestamp that makes toad hang? Also is there a way without using trunc?

Answer (score 0):

**Guess based on the information you have provided:**

It is possible that the table that you are accessing has a function based index on TRUNC(timestamp_column), which causes Oracle to retrieve the data faster.

You can use the indexes tab in toad or use all_indexes data dictionary view in Oracle and see if that is the case with your specific table and column.

I really doubt if this is a problem with Toad and Oracle time stamps in general.

Comment: Thanks. I checked..there is no function based index.